# android studio `profile or debug apk` occured IDE error

Tags: android-studio-3.0

android studio 3.0.1
I clicked 'File-> Profile or Debug APK',
but a toast showed `IDE Error Occured`.

The error's detail were:

How to fix? Thanks

[image]

[image]

------------------ 2017.12.05--------------
i quit my account on mac, then login `Guest` account.
Launch Android Studio again, NO Error Occured.

but this way is bored.